# Proving a function of matrix is convex

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have a function of a matrix and a vector $f(A,b)=y^\top (I-A)^{-1} b$ and I want to know the conditions under which it is convex.

For functions of a vector, the positive definiteness of the Hessian is sufficient to claim convexity. How do we extend this to functions of matrices? I know the first derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}=(I-A)^{-\top}y\ b^\top(I-A)^{-\top}$, but how to extend this for finding convexity?

Comment: You want convexity as a function of two variables $(A,b)$? Or do you want to find for which fixed values of $b$ the function $A \mapsto f(A,b)$ is a convex function of $A$?

Comment: I meant $f$ is a function of both $A$ and $b$. However I am struggling even with the case when $f$ is only a function of $A$.

Comment: You can always take the derivative as if the matrix were a big vector (i.e., an $n \times n$ matrix is seen as a vector with $n^2$ entries). However, you may also consider whether the definition of convexity is not easier to check: namely, whether $f(tA_1 + (1-t)A_2, tb_1 + (1-t)b_2) \leq tf(A_1,b_1) + (1-t)f(A_2,b_2)$.

Comment: It is not convex if both $A$ and $b$ are variables. One need consider only the scalar case $f(a,b)=by/(1-a)$.

Answer (score 5):

Convexity is the exception, not the rule. In my experience, nearly every question "is this function convex?" ends up being answered in the negative---because the cases where convexity is present tend to be somewhat obvious.

For general questions of computing derivatives involving vectors and matrices, the [Matrix Cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/publication_details.php?id=3274) is an essential resource.

This function is not convex, however, for any interesting case. Consider the scalar case $f(a,b)=by/(1-a)$. It is well known that the linear fractional function is neither convex nor concave, even when restricted to domains like $1-a>0$. This can be readily verified by examining the Hessian, which is indefinite.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I get the determinant of the Hessian to be $-\frac{y^2}{(a-1)^4}$, which is negative?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the determinant is (at least, not by itself). It matters what the eigenvalues are, and one is positive, and one is negative. A negative determinant does eliminate the possibility that the Hessian is positive definite, though.